# Rectangle Disappears in VS Designer When Size is Small

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

The rectangle disappears from the Visual Studio Designer when the Width is below 0.5000000000000001. It appears at runtime.

I created a Rectangle as below (boilerplate code omitted):

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Height="10" Width="0.50000000000000001" Fill="Blue" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="0"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

I was expecting to see a blue rectangle, but it is not showing in the designer. After experimenting, I discovered that if I change the width to 0.5000000000000001 or above, the rectangle will appear. I am defining this in a UserControl and scaling it later in a Window. But the rectangle still does not appear (in the user control designer or in the window designer) after being scaled. I need this to be exact because I am working on an engineering application with other geometry. They will be defined per their actual dimensions and later scaled to an appropriate size in the Window, similar to how CAD drawings work. It would be nice to see the geometry in the designer.

Comment: What version of VS? And what version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @JimFoye Hi, thanks for replying. I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Express (2017) and my application is targeting .NET Framework 4.8. I'm an unable to switch to newer editions of VS due to licensing issues.

Comment: The XAML designer for WPF applications doesn't seem to support such precise design. You might first consider using integers to define geometry dimensions, rather than using very small floating point values. The scaling factor is then applied at runtime to resize as needed.